# Stack Exchange logo appears white on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, chat, design

After leaving 'The Biosphere' and some other chatroom of Bio Stack Exchange I was taken to [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) and the site logo there displayed in white which is so obscure.

As Arulkumar mentioned in comment the exact path to reproduce would be: `https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=event&host=*`

Is it a bug?

[image]

*Edit:*

I just checked the chatroom '[The Stack Exchange Network](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11254/the-stack-exchange-network)'
*-General discussion for stackexchange.com*, looks like there's not been much useful conversation.

Comment: Exact path to reproduce: `https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=event&host=*`

Comment: *looks like there's not been much useful conversation.* Do we even have chatrooms where there is a useful conversation, except cat gifs that is?

Comment: Actually I rolled back my edit, it's not consistent. I saw it happen on the "site" tab and no other. Then it stopped. It's weird, too, because messing with the query params, or refreshing the page, changes the theme a bit then the image looks OK. The white image, when it displays, is https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/img/se-logo-white.png?v=da. I can't get a solid enough handle on it to clear it up in an edit.

Comment: It seems the issue is dependent on `host=*` and only appears to happen on the "site" tab.